# Problem with creating classmethod decorator without using @classmethod

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator

How would it work for the decorator @classmethod be created by creating your own class method that does the same thing? What does a class method do that one can implement in their own class method created?

```
class classMethod:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def method(func):
        return func
```

Comment: The [descriptor how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) provides a [pure-Python implementation of `classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods) to demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I try to implemrnt a custom `classmethod`, named `classMethod`.
I can get the same functionality from `@classMethod` and `@classmethod`.

Here is the code.

```
from functools import partial

class classMethod:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return partial(self.func, owner)
```

I write a `class` to test their functionality.

```
class Test:
    x = 'None'
    
    @classMethod
    def set_value(cls, x):
        cls.x = x
        
    # real class method
    @classmethod
    def set_the_value(cls, x):
        cls.x = x
```

```
a = Test()
b = Test()
print('The orginal Values')
print(f"{a.x=}\n{b.x=}")
print('========================')
print("use the function decorated by 'classmethod'")
Test.set_the_value('classmethod')
print(f"{a.x=}\n{b.x=}")
print('========================')
print("use the function decorated by 'classMethod'")
Test.set_value('classMethod')
print(f"{a.x=}\n{b.x=}")
```

Results.

```
The orginal Values
a.x='None'
b.x='None'
========================
use the function decorated by 'classmethod'
a.x='classmethod'
b.x='classmethod'
========================
use the function decorated by 'classMethod'
a.x='classMethod'
b.x='classMethod'
```